# Empty string is interpreted as bool in Constructor

Tags: c++, qt

Im am working on a QT project and have found a strange behaviour:

I have a class with several constructors that look like

```
DB_Variable(QString name, QString newValue):
name(name),value_string(newValue), var_type(DB_STRING){}

DB_Variable(QString name, bool newValue):
    name(name), value_bool(newValue), var_type(DB_BOOL){}
```

I now want to use the first constructor to create an object like this:

```
DB_Variable foo("some_name"," ");
```

I'd expect the empty string to be interpreted as a QString, but the second (bool) constructor is called. Can someone tell my why? Is the " " a pointer to an empty string and the then somehow rather a bool than a string?

Foo

Comment: What happens if you use `explicit` for your constructors?

Comment: For empty strings you could use `QString()` instead. `" "` - is a space, though.

Comment: @shuttle87: Exactly the same thing would happen. `explicit` prevents the constructor being used for implicit conversions, and has no effect on which conversions are applied to its arguments.

Comment: @MikeSeymour thanks, I think I had a misunderstanding of what `explicit` did and now I understand it better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem results from implicit conversions going on in the constructor. [String literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), such as the one in your code, are stored as `const char` types. Because you didn't have a constructor taking this type the compiler tries to find the conversion to a type that it can find in one of your constructors.

In this case `const char*` converts to `bool` easier that `QString` so when you do:

```
DB_Variable foo("some_name"," ");
```

The constructor

```
DB_Variable(QString name, bool newValue):
```

Is called.

Note that the behavior you are seeing isn't due to `" "` getting treated differently than any other string literal, it's just that you most likely didn't have a constructor with the types `bool, bool` (did all your constructors take a `QString` as the first argument?). Chances are if you had a constructor such as the following:

```
DB_Variable(bool test1, bool newValue):
```

Then this would have been called instead when you did something such as `DB_Variable foo("some_name"," ");`

To get the results you wanted you could pass in `QStrings` like so:

```
DB_Variable foo(QString("some_name"), QString());
```

Or perhaps define a constructor that takes `const char*` for the second parameter.

Comment: The implicit conversions aren't going on in the constructor, but before the constructor is called, in order to match its elements.

Comment: Oh I see the mistake I was making here. I edited my post accordingly.

Comment: ok. That's what I already suspected. I now added the const char* constructor so that the right function is called. Thanks!

Comment: @user3442125, glad this helped! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The string `" "` is simply a `char*`.  It converts more easily to `bool` than using a user-defined conversion to `QString`.

Comment: s/`char*`/`const char[2]`. Still has to decay before it can go to either one, though.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd expect the empty string to be interpreted as a QString, but the second (bool) constructor is called. Can someone tell my why?

`" "` gets decayed from `char[2]` to `char*`, then as a pointer it gets converted to an int, and as an int it gets converted to a bool.

I am not very familiar with Qt, but if the constructor for `QString` (that takes a char[N] or char* parameter) is explicit, then you will only engage the first constructor when you write:

```
DB_Variable foo("some_name", QString{ " " });
                   // HERE:  ^^^^^^^^     ^
```

The easiest solution to this is to add a third constructor to your DB_Variable class. You can do this in multiple ways, but if you want an empty value to be (by default) set to `" "`, you should write code similar to this:

```
DB_Variable(QString name):
name(name),value_string(" "), var_type(DB_STRING){}
```

Client code:

```
DB_Variable foo("some_name"); // create variable with empty value (actually " " value)
```