# C++ function overload resolution - bool vs string

Tags: c++, overload-resolution

I've found some unexpected behavior using the VC++2010 compiler with function overloading:

```
struct A {
  A();
  void O(const bool in);       //(1)
  void O(const std::string in);//(2)
}
```

Some of the following calls do not resolve like I would think:

```
A a;
a.O(true);//calls (1)
a.O("what?");//calls (1)
a.O(std::string("better..."));//calls (2)
```

Can someone explain to me why the second call resolves to the boolean function and what the motivation behind resolving in that way is?

Comment: This is really close since the exact same thing is happening: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24411134/empty-string-is-interpreted-as-bool-in-constructor

Answer (score 2):

The type of "what?" is `char const[6]`, which after decaying to `char const*` while being passed into the function, is implicitly convertible to `bool`. The standard conversion takes precedence over user-defined implicit conversions, like the case of converting `char const*` to `std::string`.